# Finding triangular image bounds - change of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The region R is a triangle defined by the points $(0,0)$, $(1,5)$, and $(5,1)$. We are given variable substitutions for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$:

$x = 5u + v, y = u + 5v$

The line $(0,0)$ to $(5,1)$ in R is equal to $y=\frac{x}{5}$ Substitute: $u+5v = u + \frac{v}{5}$ => $v=0$

Line $(1,5)$ to $(5,1)$ in R: $y+x=6$ => $5u+v+u+5v=6$ => $u + v=1$

Line $(0,0)$ to $(1,5)$ in R: $y=5x$ => $u+5v=25u+5v$ => $u = 0$

I am told by similar problems that this means that $0<=v<=1-u$ and $0<=u<=1$. Can someone explain why $u$ only goes from $0$ to $1$, but $v$ goes from $0$ to $1-u$? I see how you can subtract $u$ from both sides in the equation $u + v=1$, but why don't we have to subtract $v$ from both sides when finding $u$'s upper bound?

[Graph of R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r19J9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new bounds you have in terms of $u$  and  $v$ are  :  $v=0$ , $u=0$ , and  $u+v=1$, so if we try to draw this domain we get : [image]
So now can you see how to choose the new bounds in terms of  $u$ and $v$ ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I can now. I would vote you up, but I have no reputation.

Comment: @thats_how_i_feel no problem , dont worry, just mark it as accepted answer fr other users when they check the same question , you are welcome .